# unexpected ',' syntax error ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and have looked the internet to see whats wrong with this. I have tried adding spacing and removing it between the variables I'm passing but i keep getting this error:

```
25: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
student1.grades =(60,70,80)
```

Here is the code:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name,age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  def grades(math,english,science)
    @math = math
    @english = english
    @science = science
    average_grade = (math.to_i + english.to_i + science.to_i) / 3
    return average_grade
  end

  def to_s
    puts "Name = #{name}"
    puts "Age = #{age}"
    puts self.grades
  end
end

student1 = Student.new("Tom","23")
student1.grades = (60,70,80)
puts student1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grades receives three parameters. You don't do that with assignment. So change

```
student1.grades = (60,70,80)
```

to

```
student1.grades(60,70,80)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the grades for student object as

```
student1.grades(60,70,80)
```

Also minor edits.You can add the method for computing average

```
def grades_details
  average_grade = (@math.to_i + @english.to_i + @science.to_i) / 3
  return average_grade
end
```

So when you override to string u call it instead of *self.grades*

```
def to_s
  puts "Name = #{name}"
  puts "Age = #{age}"
  puts grades_details
end
```